# When using prepareForSegue in Swift, it wont load data correctly the first time the cell is clicked

Tags: ios, swift

Using the functions below it will not load the picture or the text that is retrieved from the getMore function the first time the cell is clicked. If I click on the cell it will not load until I click the back button and the re-click on the cell.The get more function sets the emailAdress, birthday, address and the url for the picture.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var indexpath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

    var destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondView
    let row: Int = indexpath.row
    getMore(row)
    destViewController.nameString = namesArray[row]
    destViewController.companyString = companyArray[row]
    destViewController.homeNumber = homeNumber[row]
    destViewController.workNumber = workNumber[row]
    destViewController.mobileNumber = mobileNumber[row]

    destViewController.emailAddress = self.email
    if let url = NSURL(string: self.largeImageURL) {
        if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
           let image1 = UIImage(data: data)
            destViewController.pic = image1!
        }        
    }


    destViewController.birthday = birthDate[row]
    destViewController.address = self.street + self.city + self.state + self.country + self.zip

}
```

Comment: Can you post `getMore`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your function getMore loads data asynchronously, so the data may not be available when you set variables.

Sure you can pass a closure in getMore function where you will set all necessary variables and use this closure when data is fully loaded, but in this case you will block the UI. I would suggest to move function getData into SecondView and call it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: i like the idea there are just too many variables in the FirstViewController that make getData function work

Comment: @PaulDragich, too many variables means you need better decoupling of functions. Make a simple struct that holds all variables and pass it in getMore function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take your image url loading off the main thread.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var indexpath : NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

    var destViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondView
    let row: Int = indexpath.row
    getMore(row)
    destViewController.nameString = namesArray[row]
    destViewController.companyString = companyArray[row]
    destViewController.homeNumber = homeNumber[row]
    destViewController.workNumber = workNumber[row]
    destViewController.mobileNumber = mobileNumber[row]

    destViewController.emailAddress = self.email

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        if let url = NSURL(string: self.largeImageURL) {
            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                    destViewController.pic = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    destViewController.birthday = birthDate[row]
    destViewController.address = self.street + self.city + self.state +      self.country + self.zip

}
```